# tkinter - Why is global variable not changed after function?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, global

```
window = Tk() #create app window



#custom message box function 
def answerMessagebox(returnValue, toplevel, functionName=""):
    global answer
    answer = returnValue

    print("The answer variable is (inside answerMessagebox function): ", answer)

    if functionName: #if there is a command do this
        functionName()

    toplevel.destroy() #close messagebox

def messageboxYesNo(title, text, functionName=""):

    toplevel = Toplevel(window)
 
    toplevel.title(title)
    
    l1=Label(toplevel, image=iconQuestion)
    l1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(7, 0), padx=(10, 30), sticky="e")

    l2=Label(toplevel,text=text)
    l2.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=(7, 10), sticky="w")
 
    b1=Button(toplevel,text="Yes",command=lambda: answerMessagebox(True, toplevel, functionName=functionName),width = 10)
    b1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(2, 35), sticky="e")

    b2=Button(toplevel,text="No",command= lambda: answerMessagebox(False, toplevel), width = 10)
    b2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(2, 35), sticky="e")



def close_window():
    driver.quit() 
    window.destroy()
    exit() 

exitButton = Button(window, text="Exit", command=lambda: messageboxYesNo("QUIT", "Are you sure you want to Quit?", functionName=close_window), font=breadtextFont, bg=button_color, fg=button_text_color) #add a exit button
exitButton.pack(side="top", anchor=NE, padx=15, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

The `print` statement inside `answerMessagebox` prints out correctly `False` if I press No-button and `True` if I press Yes-button. I want to use that answer inside another function and do logic based on the answer.

```
def foo():
    global answer
    answer = ""
    messageboxYesNo("Submit report", "Are you sure you want to submit?") #expect global variable to change to True if press Yes-button. But it actually prints out nothing. 

    if answer:
       #do something
```

Inside the `foo()`function the global variable `answer`does not change after I run the `messageboxYesNo` function and therefore the `if answer:` statements is not running.

Why is the global variable not changing? I guess it is because `foo()` continues and is not waiting for `messageboxYesNo` function to finish. How can I solve this issue?

I use a global variable because the `command=` in tkinter cannot return anything from a function.

Comment: When you set `command=` to some function, the function will get called when the Button is pressed. All your code is doing is setting that up, which is why the `print()` at the end of the function doesn't print what you're expecting (i.e. the function hasn't executed and changed the value of the global variable named `answer` at that point).

Comment: You do not provide reproducible code. Also i strongly suggest to remove complexity, e.g. by merging both things into one function without having to define global variables

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect what I really mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not show when `foo()` is being executed, however at the beginning you are already overriding the value of `answer` with an empty string, which later evaluates to false:

```py
def foo():
    global answer
    answer = "" # Remove this line
```

There are many issues with this usage of global variables, and an OOP refactor would be the best approach to address it. However, a quick solution for this specific problem would be passing the result from `answerMessagebox` to the callback:

```py
def answerMessagebox(returnValue, toplevel, functionName=""):
    answer = returnValue
    print("The answer variable is (inside answerMessagebox function): ", answer)

    if functionName:
        functionName(answer)
    # ...

def foo(answer):
    # ...
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to OOP. How can I refactor this to OOP so that I'm able to call a tkinter command and return a value from the command? (e.g. return True/False in a variable depending whether Yes-button was clicked or not)

Comment: It requires a major rewrite that goes beyond the scope of this question, but you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17466561/)

Answer (score 0):

The last print statement is executed soon after you press the `Exit` button. It simply creates the UI for the labels and the Yes/No buttons, prints the last statement and exists the function.

When you press the Yes/No buttons, it executes the `answerMessagebox` function. If you want something to execute after the changes to `answer` have been made, either add it to the end of the `answerMessagebox` function or (maybe in the case that it doesn't make sense to have it on the same function) execute a separate function at the end of the function:

```
def answerMessagebox(returnValue, toplevel, functionName=""):
    answer = returnValue
    
    # The logic you've written already
    
    toplevel.destroy() #close messagebox
    
    everythingAfterYesNoPress(answer)


def everythingAfterYesNoPress(answer = ""):
    print("This is answer variable after messageboxYesNo function", answer)
```

**Edit:**
I think what you're looking for is `wait_window`.

Initialize `toplevel` inside the `foo` function before the `messageboxYesNo` function and pass it as a parameter to the function instead of defining it inside (of course, you'd have to change the `messageboxYesNo` function a bit). Then add the `wait_window` line after executing the function:

```
toplevel = Toplevel(window)
messageboxYesNo(toplevel, "Submit report", "Are you sure you want to submit?")
window.wait_window(toplevel)
```

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect what I really mean.

Comment: @AppCreator I've edited my answer as per the changes.